# Are domain-specific cookies vulnerable to CSRF?

Tags: javascript, cookies, csrf

Let's say I set a domain-specific cookie from within the browser, like so:

```
document.cookie="foo=bar;domain=.baz.com"
```

Is this cookie susceptible to CSRF? I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this question. We currently have an auth system set up using JWT's, and I'm trying to figure out how to extend these sessions across domains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

CSRF attacks cause the victim to perform an unintended action on a site on which they are already authenticated. It works by tricking the user to submit a form (or similar action). The source of the submission can be hosted on any domain but the target is the site they are logged in to. Because the cookie was set by the original site, it will be sent along with the unintended action.

All cookies have domains. If you as a developer don't set them, the browser uses the current hostname as the domain. The fact that the domain is specifically set to match more hosts only makes the potential target sites larger.

See [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Wrong type of attack that I'm referencing, then. Is it possible for the cookie to be obtained by a 3rd party, without XSS? I'm not concerned about a request that would originate from our domain to our own backend servers, but more concerned with how a 3rd party could obtain a user's token.

Comment: Yes - man in the middle attacks or if the site is not served over `http`, then simply observing traffic such as over an open wireless network. Developers should assume that cookies will be observed by attackers and utilize a secure cookie protocol: https://www.cse.msu.edu/~alexliu/publications/Cookie/cookie.pdf